# How to install Google's chrome on CentOS 5.3?

Tags: google-chrome, centos

Google released their Chrome browser for linux but I got an error when installing. I was informed that I need a higher lsb version? What is lsb? Where can I find the latest lsb package/source ?

By the way, would it be OK if I upgrade to CentOS 5.4?

Comment: Why can't you create a statically linked binary for Linux like you can with other, more functional, unixes? That would seem to solve many of these types of problems.

Answer (score 2):

A precompiled binary is available at http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~cxs548/chrome

Comment: Strange... i just tried iton CentOS 5.5 and it complains for not finding libexpat.so.1 .CentOS 5.5 comes with libexpat 0.5

Answer (score 1):

See this thread for a further discussion on the topic

http://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos/2009-December/087045.html

And I am sure that there will be a rpm coming out soon as people are working on it follow centos on twitter.

Further you should upgrade to 5.4, can't see a reason why not.