# how to install a chrome on my RHEL 5.3 box

Tags: google-chrome, installation, rpm, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm trying to install latest chrome on my RHEL 5.3.

```
[foo@bar Downloads]# rpm -ivh "google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64(4).rpm"
warning: google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64(4).rpm: Header V4 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 7fac5991
error: Failed dependencies:
        **lsb >= 4.0** is needed by google-chrome-stable-17.0.963.56-121963.x86_64
        libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-17.0.963.56-121963.x86_64
        libcurl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-17.0.963.56-121963.x86_64
[foo@bar Downloads]# yum install lsb
epel                                                                                                                               | 3.4 kB     00:00     
2f36744c0ec6290ba30fc8af8e2d3b774cd1e443-primary.sqlite.bz2                                                                        | 3.7 MB     00:00     
google                                                                                                                             |  951 B     00:00     
primary.xml.gz                                                                                                                     | 3.2 kB     00:00     
google                                                         5/5
somecorp-linux-common                                                                                                                 | 1.1 kB     00:00     
primary.xml.gz                                                                                                                     | 5.2 kB     00:00     
somecorp-linux-common                                             17/17
vt                                                                                                                                 | 1.3 kB     00:00     
primary.xml.gz                                                                                                                     | 8.8 kB     00:00     
vt                                                             40/40
google64                                                                                                                           |  951 B     00:00     
.
.

Package **redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64** already installed and latest version
Package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[foo@bar Downloads]#
```

====================

So, What should I be doing ? I'm ready to add a bounty to get the latest chrome on my box if I have to - (I'm frustrated).

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says you are missing some dependencies to be able to run chrome. Your version of rhel needs to be upgraded to support that.

First upgrade your os `yum update -y` then try again.

Comment: This won't help, as the glibc in RHEL 5 is very old (glibc 2.5, while Chrome requires glibc 2.11 as per the error message).

Comment: Perhaps it would be possible to bastardise your system to allow for this version of glibc to be installed.

Comment: while it's possible, I don't think this is a good idea, might result in other stuff breaking.

Comment: this is work computer -- don't want to break anything and end up having headaches when it comes to finishing my tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably will not be able to run Chrome on RHEL 5, the glibc version in that distro is too old.

`libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.11)(64bit) is needed by google-chrome-stable-17.0.963.56-121963.x86_64`

But Wikipedia [says RHEL 5 comes with glibc 2.5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Libc). A possible option is [a Chromium build](http://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~cxs548/chrome), though I have not tried it (just found it [as an answer to a similar question](https://superuser.com/a/123470/118798)).